# User Control não funciona

Tags: genexus

Estou a dar os primeiros passos no que diz respeito a User Controls em Genexus e comecei por criar este simples user control:

JScript Runtime Render:

```
function test1($)
{
    this.Width;
    this.Height;

    this.show = function()
    {
        ///UserCodeRegionStart:[show] (do not remove this comment.)
        var buffer = "<p> hello </p>";
        this.setHtml(buffer);

        ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.)
    }
    ///UserCodeRegionStart:[User Functions] (do not remove this comment.)

    ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.):
}
```

O único tab que editei foi mesmo esse em que apenas adicionei as linhas:

```
        var buffer = "<p> hello </p>";
        this.setHtml(buffer);
```

Quando adiciono o user control a um web panel o resultado depois de correr a aplicação é uma pagina web vazia, nem sequer aparece o footer e header da pagina.

Eu também segui o tutorial do HelloWorld para fazer uma User control, mas o resultado da pagina também fica totalmente vazio (em branco). O que está de errado aqui? Falta fazer alguma coisa?

Estou usando a versão 3 trial.

Comment: En la consola de Google Chrome o Firefox, aparece algún error? En Google Chrome se abre con F12.

Comment: Sim foi um grande erro meu não ter começado por ir ver a consola!
Sim, logo quando o browser é aberto tenho este erro:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf92d5b5d4d440bb6389f30e202ac93d5/gxmetadata/sdap‌​ps.json?0.8899557499680668`

Comment: Quando abro o web panel tenho este erro:
`GET http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf92d5b5d4d440bb6389f30e202ac93d5/test1/test1.js 404 (Not Found)`

Mas o ficheiro test1.js está na mesma directoria onde está test1.control que o genexus reconhece.
O que posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Você poderia por favor me passe o url do Web Panel não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Você já executou um Genexus.exe /install com o genexus fechado e depois um force o Build no objeto que deseja testar

- [HowTo: Installing User Controls](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?5920)